# Cannot remove css mouse over effect

Tags: css, frontend, extensions, phtml

My problem seems simple, but I actually spent 4 hours looking for the problem and can't find it.

I have a plug-in in magento to show a banner slider in my frontend page together with an image below the banner. My issue here is that, the image below the banner do not have hyper-links and still when you put the *mouse over* the image, an *1px grey border appears* around it and it receives *opacity*.

I went throw every css file I found in my magento folder and could not find the source. [The website is here](http://www.lojaanalitica.com.br)

Is it possible to use the !important feature of css to solve the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This is css qst, but here is my answer.

Remove this code from your css: `styles-vendor.css` line 2684 (http://lojaanalitica.com.br/skin/frontend/venedor/default/css/styles-venedor.css)

```
.main-banner img:hover {

    opacity :0.85; 

    filter: alpha(opacity=85);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it helped, could you mark it right answer to help others.